# how do i place a list of strings into dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to place the list of string which i am getting from my database into drop-down menu. i have try using array but it shows me an error of [[object Object, object Object]...]. This is my ajax method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        Method(); });

function Method() {
        ajReq.abort();
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetService",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (x) {
                  var opts = '';
                $.each(x, function (i) {
                    opts += '<option>' + this + '</option>';
                });
                $('.dropdown-menu').html(opts);
             }
        });
    }
```

> this is my drop down menu:

```
 <div class="fromDropdownMenu" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="Button1" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span id="dropdown_title">Name:</span><span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

currently if i place a breakpoint to $.each(x, function (i)  and hoverover x i get [[object Object], [object, Object]...]. If i then click on + sign i get my data from the database.

But when the breakpoint hits opts += '' + this + ''; and if i hoverover  i get same message as [[object Object], [object, Object]...] if i then click on + sign i get Children could not be evaluated. Same message shows. Can someone help me here?

This is what my x is:

```
     -      x   {...}   Object
-       d   [[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]           Object, (Array)
-       [0] {...}   Object
+       __type  "MakeBooking"   String
    MakeBookingID   0   Number
+       Name    "Jhon"  String
+       [1] {...}   Object
+       [2] {...}   Object
+       [3] {...}   Object
+       arguments   {...}   Object, (Arguments)
    opts    ""  String
```

This is onselect function:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function () {
            $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
        });
```

Comment: i have placed what i get when i click on top of x. as you can see x contains Name "Jhon" so there are four names i am trying to get from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `x` is an object, not an array, and the data you want to display is inside `x.d`. Furthermore, `x.d` is not an array of strings, but an array of objects, containing the property `Name`.

Finally the `.dropdown-menu` element is a `<ul>`, so rather than use `<option>` for child elements use `<li>` instead:

```
success: function (x) {
    var opts = '';
    $.each(x.d, function (i) {
        opts += '<li>' + this.Name + '</li>';
    });
    $('.dropdown-menu').html(opts);
}
```

Or even better:

```
success: function (x) {
    $.each(x.d, function (i) {
        $('<li>').text(this.Name).appendTo('.dropdown-menu');
    });
}
```

Comment: your a star :) Thank you. just a final question, currently i am getting names as JhonDipeshCharly how do i separate then so that each name is in different line?

Comment: once again thank you it works. I have a final final question. Now that all the names are being placed into a dropdown menu. is there any way i can select them? i got the code for select but where would i place that code? I have placed the code at the end of my question

Comment: @Dip Looks like you just need a space in your selector: `$(".dropdown-menu li").click(...);`